# sshpass -e not working in script when fired from cron

Tags: linux, ssh, cron, sshpass

I am running the below command in a script.
$findoutput=`sshpass -e ssh $CONFIG_PARAMS{'xxxx'}\@$CONFIG_PARAMS{'xxxx'} \"find $CONFIG_PARAMS{'xx'} -name \\\"*.cfg.gz\\\"`;

sshpass -e runs fine when i run the script manually.

Whereas when the script runs in cron, i get the below error:

Usage: sshpass [-f|-d|-p|-e] [-hV] command parameters
   -f filename   Take password to use from file
   -d number     Use number as file descriptor for getting password
   -p password   Provide password as argument (security unwise)
   -e            Password is passed as env-var "SSHPASS"
   With no parameters - password will be taken from stdin
   -P prompt     Which string should sshpass search for to detect a password   prompt
   -v            Be verbose about what you're doing
   -h            Show help (this screen)
   -V            Print version information
At most one of -f, -d, -p or -e should be used

Any pointers would be helpful. Ideally after ssh, the find command should fail as the path will not be available.

Comment: `-e` reads the password from env var `$SSHPASS`. so how did u set `$SSHPASS` for the cron job?

Comment: and please format your post. see https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: @pynexj
sorry, i have formatted my post. 
can you please let me know how $SSHPASS from /etc/profile has to be passed to cron script ?

Comment: Thanks the below worked.
* * * * * source /etc/profile; cd /home/manu/; ./manu.pl manu.config